# Javafx: How to set a scaled image as a node background

Tags: java, css, image, javafx-2, image-quality

I have a simple JavaFX program that uses an image for the background on the main `Pane`. Currently I'm loading the image directly in my `.css` file:

```
.pane {
  -fx-background-image: url('map.png');
  -fx-background-size: 1000 800;
}
```

This works fine, but the quality of the image `-fx-background-size` generates is rather poor.

Instead I'd like to use [`java.awt.Image#getScaledInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance-int-int-int-) with [`Image.SCALE_SMOOTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#SCALE_SMOOTH) (or the JavaFX equivalent), which generates an image of much higher quality.

Can I use `getScaledInstance` directly and somehow pass a Java `awt` image to my css file? Or inline it with `setStyle`?

I'm aware that since this image is only being resized once I could just resize the original image and import that, but I'd like to know if what I want to do is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I needed to do was remove my CSS and simply do:

```
Pane root = new Pane();
ImageView background = new ImageView(new Image("map.png", 1000, 800, false, true));
root.getChildren().add(background);
```

This is because the JavaFX equivalent of `java.awt.Image#getScaledInstance` is just in the constructor for `javafx.scene.image.Image`.

While you can't use a `java.awt.Image` in place of a `javafx.scene.image.Image`, using [this `javafx.scene.image.Image` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-double-double-boolean-boolean-):

```
Image(String url, double width, double height, boolean preserveRatio, boolean smooth)
```

and passing `true` as the value for the `smooth` field will give a similar quality image as `getScaledInstance` using `Image.SCALE_SMOOTH`.
Then (as @kylejmcintyre mentioned) you can pass the `javafx.scene.image.Image` to an `ImageView` object and add it to your root `Pane`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `StackPane` as the root node on your `Scene` and then put an instance of `ImageView` at the bottom of the stack and put whatever you were previously using as your root on top of it with a transparent background color (defined in CSS or programmatically).

Obviously this circumvents CSS, but perhaps it will suffice and allow you to achieve the scaling you want.

Comment: Oh, also, you'll want to bind the width/height of your stackpane to the width/height of the scene.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure consistency when resizing the window/stage. This is what I did

Create a root node

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
```

Get the primary-screen

```
Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
```

Set the visible bounds of your screen

```
Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
double width = bounds.getWidth();
double height = bounds.getHeight();
```

Set a background image with the same size as the size of the screen.
When you resize the screen, the background image will be resized too since you've set the
width and the height of the image as that of the current screen size.

```
BackgroundImage bImage = new BackgroundImage(new 
Image("url here",width,height,false,true),
    BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
      BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);

root.setBackground(new Background(bImage));
```

Test the program by displaying it

```
stage.setTitle("Title here);
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.show();
```

I hope it helped you. Keep Java alive